# What are the purple streaks and splotches in my peach tree leaves?

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, diseases, peaches

I live in Southern New England and have a peach tree growing in the ground in my yard. I have had it for about two years. The weather this summer has been fairly warm, averaging mid to upper 80s.

I am seeing purple streaks / blotches in some of my cherry leaves along with holes that appear to be insect damage. Damaged leaves fall out easily. The discoloration is not uniform but appears most often in the center of each leaf. The majority of the plant other than some of its leaves look very healthy. See picture below. This is the same plant I talked about in [my other question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/33748/what-are-these-galls-in-my-peach-leaves) here.

What is causing the damage to the leaves of my peach tree?

[image]

Comment: Alina's answer for the 'galls' looks very credible.  Again, trees that aren't healthy because they don't have access to the basic 3 macro chemicals (nutrients) or the dozen or so micro nutrients will be susceptible to anything that is around.  Otherwise, healthy plants can protect themselves.  Akin to our immune system.  Tell us what you have done with adding these necessary chemical (nutrients) for your tree...thanks!

Comment: He actually put that into his question as a reference.  His problem is still the same, his tree is not healthy enough to do battle with insects and disease.  I'll go check out what I have said...

Comment: My answer was directed to his one picture only.  I commented on his other question concerning the 'galls' but my answer is about chemical deficiency being the main cause. I am glad you saw Cherry and Peach because I was shaking my head...regardless of the species of tree, I am seeing chemical (nutrient) deficiencies.

Answer (score 1):

Anthony, I am sending a site of images showing phosphorus deficiency.  Purple is pretty indicative of phosphorus deficiency.  Have you used any fertilizer for this tree?  Plants have to have the proper amount of chemicals (nutrients) just like the proper amount of water, drainage and light to make their own food and support their own health.  Looks rather anemic as well meaning toolittle nitrogen or the iron is off. Are you able to test the pH of the soil? Let me know what you've done in this regard.  Is this tree in the middle of the lawn?  Do you fertilize your lawn?  Insects and disease aren't the main problem anyway.  A weakened plant, one that isn't able to make its own food via photosynthesis and is slowly dying will be subject to insects and diseases.  [phosphorus deficiency symptoms on leaves of differing genus/species](https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=A86.JyhOQLRZ_l8A5sAnnIlQ?p=phosphorus%20deficiency&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&fr2=piv-web&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002)

[Nitrogen deficiency symptoms on peach leaves](https://images.search.yahoo.com/yhs/search;_ylt=AwrTccsNRLRZdIAASUEnnIlQ?p=Nitrogen%20dificiency%20peach&fr=yhs-mozilla-002&fr2=piv-web&hspart=mozilla&hsimp=yhs-002)

This second link looks pretty familiar, yes?